# Is the C language copyrighted and is there any terms of use use for that?

Tags: c

I searched about copyright of programming languages and about C language i didn't see copyright notice for that, So I want to know is there any copyright for that or not? and there is no terms and conditions or limitations for using this language? In fact, I wanted to know that the C language has its own terms of use (regardless of the compilers ToU) that make a person no longer able to program in that language due to its violation of terms of use, I think this is not and this language does not have certain conditions for use and can be used under any circumstances unless the user is limited to the terms of the compiler which he use, It's right?

Comment: No. C is an ISO standard. They copyright the specification documents, but the languages that are specified are free to use.

Comment: @Irelia: The ISO C standard certainly is copyrighted.

Comment: @Irelia, (The last draft of) the standard [disagrees](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bRNpg.png). Even without notice, Copyright attaches *automatically* these days. (Since 1976, I think.)

Comment: The *document* is copyrighted. The standard itself is not.

Comment: @DevSolar, The document is the standard. It's right there in the image I posted.

Comment: I think DevSolar means to say that the langauge which the standard defines is not copyrighted

Comment: This question is better posted on [Law StackExchange](https://law.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 3):

Copyright covers works of authorship *fixed in a tangible medium of expression*  and within the subject matter of copyright.

This means a language can't be Copyrighted.

The standard can be Copyrighted. The ISO/IEC owns that Copyright.

Compilers can be Copyrighted. gcc, clang, VC are all Copyrighted.

But anyone can create a their compiler. If you write one, that is your program and its Copyright would belong to you as the author (unless it's a work for hire).

---

Trademark is another story. Trademarks apply to identifiers (names, logos, etc). It's a consumer protection law.

I don't believe "C" is trademarked. A trademark would prevent others from saying they have a C compiler even if it was able to compile C programs, unless they first obtained permission (i.e. a license).

Comment: so the only terms of use for coding in C is compliers ToU and there's no limitation for using C language and it's free to use in any case?

Comment: All languages are free to use. Just like natural languages. Compilers might not be.

Comment: thanks, so for example if I'm coding In C with compiler A and the owner of that terminate my rights of using his compiler ( for violation of ToU of his compiler), Can I keep coding in C by compiler B, that's right?

Comment: yes. __________

Comment: It was a bit more murky: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_LLC_v._Oracle_America,_Inc. Alsup's district court ruling (IMO) was correct. But, the appellate court reversed it. If that had been upheld, it was tantamount to conferring patent protections to a copyrighted work: Because Oracle copyrighted the Java language [API] spec, it could control who could use the language. Fortunately, the Supreme Court overturned this in April 2021.

Comment: @Craig Estey, "ruling was correct" and "tantamount to conferring patent protections to a copyrighted work" are contradictory sentences. Copyright protects works but not ideas, and patents protect ideas but not works. The initial ruling was a *horrible* ruling. It meant that you could control the idea that a specific function took an `int` for a parameter. And that's a blatant misuse of Copyright. It literally protected things that *weren't* "fixed in a tangible medium of expression" (an API as opposed to a header file). To call Copyrighting ideas "murky" is one hell of an understatement.

Comment: @ikegami thanks a lot! with your answers I realized that the C language in any case is free to use but compiler apps may be not, So I always have the right to code in C , but in your first answer you said "The standard can be Copyrighted. The ISO/IEC owns that Copyright." so what is this "standard", If a person violated that copyright, will he still have the right to use and coding in C ? Because you said using C is free, So I think there's no problem for using C even violated the copyright of that standard. Is it right?

Comment: Copyright prevents copying, derivative works, a few other non-relevant rights. As long you don't copy or modify the standard, you don't have to worry about that.

Comment: @ikegami thanks, so for example, if person A created a software for himself by coding in C language, and the person B break person A's software codes by C language, in here person B just violated the copyright of person A but he still can use C language, Yes?

Comment: It's not clear what "break" means, but violating A's Copyright has no effect on one's ability to code in C.

Comment: @ikegami By breaking I meant something like cracking the software to use it for free, and I think it's not related to person's right for using C language, Can you give an example of changing or copying the standard so that I can understand exactly what works can require the copyright of the C language standard?

Comment: @user19456128, Well, if I gave you a copy of the standard, that would be a Copyright violation, so I can do that!

Comment: @ikegami Well, If I violate C language standard copyright, the copyright owner can sue me for that, it's normal, but even in this time I can use that standard and C language for programming like other people without violating copyright, because I think violating copyright of standard and using that or separate and not related to each other and violation of that will not effect on your right to using that in correct way, Yes?

Comment: @ikegami ? ? ? ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246111/discussion-between-user19456128-and-ikegami).